Notification clearing
Sometimes I follow a question as it's interesting but not something I can contribute to as I don't know the language itself, not as much experience, whatever the reason.
I then get X amount of notifications, which is great, but I think if I click on one notification, they should be marked as read and clear the inbox for that question. Clicking and therefore clearing notifications for every comment and edit is redundant. I went there, saw the changes, I get it.
"Mark all as read" is iffy as the inbox isn't cleared reliably, and I need to refresh for it to go away.
Related
Inbox notifications not consistently marked as read after clicking title
Same-type notifications on a followed post should appear once in the inbox
